# EF Core: Combine two rows pairwise

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using .NET 7 and SQL Server.

I have a table in SQL Server like this:

```
[Id] BIGINT IDENTITY(1, 1),
[Start] DATETIMEOFFSET NOT NULL,
[End] DATETIMEOFFSET NOT NULL,
[FromPersonId] INT NOT NULL,
[ToPersonId] INT NOT NULL,
[AmountUsd] DECIMAL NOT NULL,
```

I would like to use EF Core and produce objects that look like this:

```cs
public record PersonMoneyTransferDto(DateTimeOffset Start, DateTimeOffset End, 
                                     decimal AmountToUsd, decimal AmountFromUsd);

public record AllPersonsMoneyTransfersDto(string PersonName, 
   IReadOnlyCollection< PersonMoneyTransferDto> MoneyTransfersToThisPerson);
```

This way, I can get a list of transfers (both directions) to other people wrt. to a given person. In this scenario, persons can exchange money in every one of these time slots in both directions, but the transfers are stored in the database as one transfer per row.

I am stuck on how to do this with EF Core/SQL Server. I have thought about using `SelectMany` but I haven't produced anything that worked yet.

How can I combine the rows so two potential rows with the same `Start` and `End` become one object with amounts in both directions?

**EDIT:**

Entity classes:

```cs
public class MoneyTransfer
{
    public long Id { get; private set; }

    public decimal AmountUsd { get; private set; }

    public DateTimeOffset Start { get; private set; }
    public DateTimeOffset End { get; private set; }

    public virtual Person FromPerson { get; private set; }
    public virtual Person ToPerson { get; private set; }

    // Constructor for EF
    private MoneyTransfer() { }
}

public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string FullName { get; private set; }

    // Constructor for EF
    private Person() { }
}
```

Comment: How we can help without entity classes and result DTO? What you have tried also?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I have added entity classes. The result DTO is the one already in the post.

Comment: How `Start`  and `End` is related to `AmountToUsd` and `AmountFromUsd`? It should be grouped by `Start` and `End`?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv `Start` and `End` define the period the transaction happened in. Therefore the transactions should be grouped by `Start` and `End`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve here. If you are looking to group db entities by pair of start/end then convert entries into a single DTO, the following code will do that:

```cs
public class Adapter
{
    private readonly TestDbContext context;

    public Adapter(TestDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public async Task<AllPersonsMoneyTransfersDto> GetAllTransfers(string name)
    {
        return new AllPersonsMoneyTransfersDto
        {
            PersonName = name,
            MoneyTransfersToThisPerson = await context.MoneyTransfer
                .Where(xfer => xfer.FromPerson.Name == name || xfer.ToPerson.Name == name)
                .GroupBy(xfer => new { xfer.Start, xfer.End })
                .Select(group => new PersonMoneyTransferDto
                {
                    Start = group.Key.Start,
                    End = group.Key.End,
                    AmountFromUsd = group.First(xfer => xfer.FromPerson.Name == name).AmountUsd,
                    AmountToUsd = group.First(xfer => xfer.ToPerson.Name == name).AmountUsd,
                }).ToArrayAsync()
        };
    }
}
```

The above code will fail if there is a start/end couple without both entries. If you want to handle that case, you need to make `MoneyTransfer.AmountUsd` nullable and add a default value after each `First()` statement.